# Jackson @JsonIgnore fields based on spring security roles

Tags: json, spring, serialization, jackson

In all of my Spring REST Web application, I have a lot of domain objects and DTOs.

I need to filter some domain object or DTOs fields based on the spring security roles of the user who makes the request. I want Jackson to filter the output JSON to allow/disallow specific class fields to be serialized , based on the Spring GrantedAuthorities roles of the user who tries to access the resource.

I can't create new DTO for every different view combination because it would be a mess.

I have found this solution :
[Spring 3.2: Filtering Jackson JSON output based on Spring Security role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276081/spring-3-2-filtering-jackson-json-output-based-on-spring-security-role)
But it doesn't work, the filter is only applied once, when the first user logins. Then all the other users obtain the same filtering , no matter what their role is.

I cannot explain my problem better than Ray Holland on this blog post :
http://jackson-users.ning.com/forum/topics/jackson-custom-serialization
This is the exact same problem I'm trying to solve for a few days.

I couldn't find a clean way to do that so far.

Comment: create multiple mapper with different views, configured will that helps

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `@JsonView` in spring project ([example](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring))

If `@JsonView` isn't enough, there isn't easy solution. It is unavoidable to define specific class(interface) to implement `@JsonIgnoreProperties` and `@JsonFilter` (
take a look [Jackson: Skip Objects Conditionally](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria) )