# What is the best practice to create dynamic dto's based on access levels?

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, dynamic, dto

My question is that I have a java spring application using input and output `DTO` with several fields, besides I have an `api` to update my data models using this `DTO`. My input `DTO` is something like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class UpdateUser extends AbstractPortable {

@NotNull
@Size(min = 5, max = 255)
private String address;

@Size(min = 1, max = 10)
@Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]*$")
private String birthCertificateNumber;

@Size(min = 1, max = 2)
@Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]*$")
private String birthCertificateSeriesNumber;

@Past
@Schema(description = "{\"validators\":[\"age > 18\"]}")
private LocalDateTime birthDate;

@Size(min = 3, max = 50)
private String englishCompanyName;

@Size(min = 3, max = 255)
private String description;

@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp = "^(.+)@(\\S+)$")
private String emailAddress;

@Size(min = 3, max = 50)
private String englishFatherName;

@Pattern(regexp = "^[1-9][0-9]{3,7}$")
private String faxNumber;

@Size(min = 3, max = 50)
private String englishFirstName;

@Size(min = 3, max = 50)
private String englishLastName;

@NationalCode
private String nationalCode;

@Future
@Schema(description = "{\"validators\":[\"passportExpireDate < now\"]}")
private LocalDateTime passportExpireDate;

@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp = "^(?!^0+$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}$\n")
private String passportNumber;

@PastOrPresent
private LocalDateTime registerDate;

@Pattern(regexp = "^[1-9][0-9]{3,7}$")
private String telephoneNumber;

private Reference<Long> residenceCity;

private Reference<Long> birthCountry;

}
```

The problem is that I want to limit updating on this `DTO's` based on my access controls... I just want user not to see some fileds based on their access level. I dont want to tell the UI team not to show some fields to the user and I want to pass this limitation to UI from my business side.
The final point is that I check user token to control access control.
How can I create a dynamic `DTO` based on access control?
What is the best practice to implement this?

Comment: maybe this contains something you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558218/jackson-jsonignore-fields-based-on-spring-security-roles

Comment: You are already using annotations, so why not continue down that path? Create field level annotation that takes the access control as a value, and using reflection get the applicable fields based on what the access level is.

Comment: @jokarl can you provide me with an example how I can include my access level in annotation. I check token to control access level. I will be really thankful for your help,

Comment: @NahidBandi if the answer above mine is of no help I can write a quick example. Could you updated your question with code on how you handle the access control? Is it an enum? String value? I'm not too familiar with Spring

Comment: @AmirSchnell the problem with this solution is that we cannot apply multiple view for the same controller. I want the same controller to have different behaviors based on access controls.... I will appreciate any suggestion or help.